# xUnit Visual Studio Runner - "TestCaseFilter" Option Does not Work?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, xunit, xunit.net

We have few xUnit.net tests we would like to execute using `VSTest.Console.exe`. I'm using the [official](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099) xUnit Visual Studio Runner in order to do so. It's working great, but I wasn't able to filter tests using the `/TestCaseFilter` parameter.

Here is what the test looks like:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "Sanity")]
Public void MyTest() {
    DoSomething();
}
```

I'm running the following command:

`VSTest.Console.exe Test.dll /TestCaseFilter:"Category=Sanity" /UseVsixExtensions:true`

For some reason, all the tests in the DLL are getting executed instead just the one with the sanity trait on it. I was able to find the [following](https://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/terje2000/TerjeTFS/contribution/3759), where it's stated this issue might not reproduce on xUnit 2.0. I compiled the latest Test Runner from Beta 3, but I'm stilling having the same issue.

Before I'm posting a bug/request, I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something? Did someone manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me either. But I'm not using the VSIX extension directly, instead I'm using the xUnit test adapter runner in a build controller on Visual Studio Online where I specify the TestCaseFilter in the Build Definition. However the behaviour should be similar to your problem. The only sources that made it work was [this pull request](https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/pull/10). Unfortunately it was never merged with the original branch.